# Error: -69519 when resizing partition of apfs container scheme

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, partition, apfs, guid

I am trying to resize the partition `disk0s2` in my Mac. My `diskutil list` shows:

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *121.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         60.6 GB    disk0s2
   3:       Microsoft Basic Data                         209.7 MB   disk0s3

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +60.6 GB    disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume macOs - Data            46.4 GB    disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 82.6 MB    disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                525.8 MB   disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      1.1 GB     disk1s4
   5:                APFS Volume macOs                   11.1 GB    disk1s5
```

and my `diskutil apfs list`:

```
APFS Container (1 found)
|
+-- Container disk1 8C3CDC58-CC44-4C3D-AD28-F03925313A0F
    ====================================================
    APFS Container Reference:     disk1
    Size (Capacity Ceiling):      60561534976 B (60.6 GB)
    Capacity In Use By Volumes:   59352715264 B (59.4 GB) (98.0% used)
    Capacity Not Allocated:       1208819712 B (1.2 GB) (2.0% free)
    |
    +-< Physical Store disk0s2 062BA902-EB8D-4DF0-9765-7DEA85E8CF79
    |   -----------------------------------------------------------
    |   APFS Physical Store Disk:   disk0s2
    |   Size:                       60561534976 B (60.6 GB)
    |
    +-> Volume disk1s1 31BAEA1D-A9A7-4FB8-9715-799815340E26
    |   ---------------------------------------------------
    |   APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk1s1 (Data)
    |   Name:                      macOs - Data (Case-insensitive)
    |   Mount Point:               /System/Volumes/Data
    |   Capacity Consumed:         46438572032 B (46.4 GB)
    |   FileVault:                 No
    |
    +-> Volume disk1s2 E195C9A9-5014-466D-BF1F-BC0CD64F5A5F
    |   ---------------------------------------------------
    |   APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk1s2 (Preboot)
    |   Name:                      Preboot (Case-insensitive)
    |   Mount Point:               Not Mounted
    |   Capacity Consumed:         82649088 B (82.6 MB)
    |   FileVault:                 No
    |
    +-> Volume disk1s3 48CA81D5-5C73-41B3-8880-3A9C6BB1D33F
    |   ---------------------------------------------------
    |   APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk1s3 (Recovery)
    |   Name:                      Recovery (Case-insensitive)
    |   Mount Point:               /Volumes/Recovery
    |   Capacity Consumed:         525787136 B (525.8 MB)
    |   FileVault:                 No
    |
    +-> Volume disk1s4 F651611C-EC8C-440A-897B-C27CA5BDB0D5
    |   ---------------------------------------------------
    |   APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk1s4 (VM)
    |   Name:                      VM (Case-insensitive)
    |   Mount Point:               /private/var/vm
    |   Capacity Consumed:         1074814976 B (1.1 GB)
    |   FileVault:                 No
    |
    +-> Volume disk1s5 97B73362-8020-4C32-A659-652EAAF8893D
        ---------------------------------------------------
        APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk1s5 (System)
        Name:                      macOs (Case-insensitive)
        Mount Point:               /
        Capacity Consumed:         11110051840 B (11.1 GB)
        FileVault:                 No
```

However, when I try to resize my container `disk0s2` by:

```
diskutil ap resizeContainer disk0s2 0
```

I get:

```
Started APFS operation
Aligning grow delta to 29.438.464.000 bytes and targeting a new physical store size of 89.999.998.976 bytes
Determined the maximum size for the targeted physical store of this APFS Container to be 60.561.534.976 bytes
Error: -69519: The target disk is too small for this operation, or a gap is required in your partition map which is missing or too small, which is often caused by an attempt to grow a partition beyond the beginning of another partition or beyond the end of partition map usable space
```

I have about 60GB free in my disk0, but it is not even being showed up in my `Disk Utility`:

[image]

How can I add this 60Gb free on my `disk0s2`??

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is usually caused by the existence of another partition. In your case, this would probably be the partition associated with the identifier `disk0s3`. If you do not need this partition, then the command below with remove the partition

```
sudo diskutil erasevolume free none disk0s3
```

You then can try entering the command given in your question.

If you first want to confirm this partition is causing the problem, the edit your question and post the output from the following commands.

```
diskutil info disk0s2 | grep -e Offset -e Size
diskutil info disk0s3 | grep -e Offset -e Size
```