# Internal NVMe SSD missing 65GB after uninstalling Boot Camp with Boot Camp Manager

Tags: bootcamp, partition, ssd, diskutil

I am attempting to reclaim the 65GB or so I previously partitioned using Boot Camp Assistant. I have tried another answer listed before to the same problem however I could not get it to work. I have a 250GB~ NVMe SSD with my Mac Mini 2018 but only 185GB is showing up as useable. Disk Utility shows the SSD has 250GB but I can not partition off the additional space, everything shows as if it never existed. Please help!

[image: Drive listed with diskutil]

Comment: Try `diskutil eraseVolume free none disk0s3`, then enter `diskutil apfs resizeContainer disk0s2 0`.

Comment: @DavidAnderson Thank you very much! You have solved my issue :)

Comment: imEthan: Generally, questions that are duplicates are flagged as such. In this case, your question is similar to "[Error: -69519 when resizing partition of apfs container scheme](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/414885/error-69519-when-resizing-partition-of-apfs-container-scheme)". Note: The answer to both questions is exactly the same.

Answer (score 1):

Following David Anderson's comment I ran

```
diskutil eraseVolume free none disk0s3
```

followed by

```
diskutil apfs resizeContainer disk0s2 0
```

and it worked perfectly.